# How do I remove applied css on a div by JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

At the start of my application, I have added a loading page. To have this loading page viewed as the first page of my applicatioin, I added a `display: none` to the global div of my second page.

After some second, I want to remove this `display: none` css from my global div, without removing the whole css class of this div. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to set the display property to whatever you want it to be:

```
$("#myDiv").css("display", "block");
```

Alternatively:

```
$("#myDiv").show();
```

Comment: Note that `show()` also save the previous state of the div. So it might be just what you want or something that saves undesired data for no use.

Comment: _"This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'block'), except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline."_

Comment: @gdoron - nice, thanks for the reference. I didn't know that. I normally steer away from `.show()` because it can lead to confusing situations, e.g. when you need something like `display: table-cell` or `inline-block`

Comment: @gdoron. I thougt the answer I selected was before this answer. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @karim79, congratulations... :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#divId").css("display", "");
```

Or:

```
$("#divId").css("display", "block");
```

Or:

```
$("#divId").css("display", "what you want");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your div as an id, you could simply do that:

```
$('#your_div_id').css('display', 'block');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either do:

```
$('#div').show();
```

Or if you want to explicitly change the CSS value:

```
$('#div').css('display', 'block');
```